Creating VSCode custom editor for files without extension
I am looking to create a custom extension that would show output of objdump when an executable is opened inside VSCode.
Looks like the custom editor extension point expects a glob pattern. Executables on Unixes do not have a set extension. How can I declare a custom editor in this case?

I'm not familiar with making extensions so I will just leave a comment. Could you execute the file command, parse the output, and then determine whether or not the file is an executable that way? A less safe option would be checking the file permissions to see if it's executable. Or are file globs your only avenue?

@Confettimaker the question is not how to understand if the file is executable (this is easy) but how to associate the custom editor with those files.

Well, good luck! Please report back if you figure it out before someone else answers.

I for one can't think of a way around this right now.
You could open a feature-request issue ticket asking for some way to get this.
I for one imagine asking for a selector alternative to filenamePattern that instead matches a language mode, and then using the existing language contribution point to solve this particular issue. Since your use-case is for objdump, if you have an ELF binary, then I'm going to wager a guess you can do something with firstLine in contributes.languages. Maybe something along the lines of "firstLine": "^\\x7FELF", or "firstLine": "^\\x7FELF.*",. If you wanted to be more strict than that, you could start validating further. Such as "firstLine": "^\\x7FELF[\\x01-\\x02]{2}\\x01[\\x01-\\x12]", and so on. Depending on use-case, you could maybe use mimetype instead. Ex. "mimetype": "application/x-executable".

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.
